# Generic methods returning generic interface-implementing types in java?

Tags: generics, methods, interface

Can methods in java be used to return generics implementing a specified interface?

You can do the following with abstract classes :

```
 public <T extends myClass> T myFunct(T[] args){};
```

So I was wondering how you'd implement something like:

```
 public <T implements myInterface> T myFunct(T[] args){};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well nobody has answered so far but I figured you could create an abstract class that implements and interface and return a type that extends that abstract class.

```
 public abstract myAbstractClass implements myInterface{
      //in here you put interface methods
 }
```

then you'd be able to do things like

```
 public <T extends myAbstractClass> myFunct(T[] args){}
```

But if anyone has a better solution please post.